# NGINX location fallback to Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, nginx-location

I'm working on a legacy API project written in pure PHP and now trying to move it to Symfony 4 and need to make some changes to the NGINX configuration.

I am required to keep both the old and the new endpoints working at the same time, so my plan is to setup NGINX in a way that it tries to serve first the old endpoint and if it doesn't exist (since I plan to remove them as I migrate to Symfony) it redirects to Symfony's front controller.

The current directory structure is this:

[image: Directory structure]

So far my NGINX conf is like so:

```
server {

  root /project/www;
  index index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

  location ~ / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

}
```

It works fine, if I request `/api/client_status` it uses the `index.php` under the `client_status` directory and if I remove that folder it uses Symfony's front controller. 
 The thing is that other applications are using these enpoints sometimes with index.php appended, e.g `/api/client_status/index.php`, and in these cases I get a 404 instead of being redirected to Symfony's front controller.

I tried rewriting at the top of the server block with rewrite `^/api/(.*)/index.php /api/$1;` but it didn't help. Any input or even a suggestion of another approach is very welcome.

Comment: You could try adding `try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;` to your `location ~ \.php$` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith, that did the trick, thanks so much! If you add this comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URIs with `index.php` appended, will be processed by the `location ~ \.php$`. You need to add a `try_files` statement to this block to avoid the 404 responses, and instead send the requests to Symfony's front controller.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    ...
}
```